# Организация системы тегов

Tags: теги, php, база-данных, mysql

Есть таблицы:

```
Item
| id | itemName | value | desc |

tag
| id | tagName |

ItemTag
| id | itemId | tagId |
```

Сейчас научился только получать 10 последних записей.

```
SELECT * FROM  `Item` ORDER BY  `Item`.`itemName` DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

Кроме этого получать имена тегов и itemId:

```
SELECT tag.nameTag, itemTag.itemId FROM tag LEFT JOIN itemTag ON itemTag.tagId=tag.tagId WHERE itemTag.itemId IN (1, 2, 3) ORDER BY itemTag.itemId ASC
```

Получается, что у меня минимум два запроса, плюс php нужно переварить информацию.

Был бы рад, если бы вы подсказали как объединить результаты в один красивый и эффективный запрос. Желательно, чтоб была примерно такая штука (покажу в JSON):

```
[
  {
    1,      //itemId
    'Nhnn', //itemName
    ['tag1', 'tag20', 'tag76'],
  },
  {<br>
    2,
    'Nhnn2',
    ['tag10', 'tag201'],
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Объединение запросов по элементам и их тегам, группировка по id элементов, сбор связанных тегов в одну колонку

```
SELECT Item.itemId, Item.itemName, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tag.tagName separator ',') tags
FROM Item
LEFT JOIN ItemTag ON ItemTag.itemId = Item.itemId
JOIN tag ON tag.Id = ItemTag.tagId
WHERE itemTag.itemId IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY itemTag.itemId
ORDER BY itemTag.itemId ASC
```

Документация

- [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)
- [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)
- [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)